# sql join statement and deliberately repeat first line in every group

Tags: sql, join

I have Header and Detail file (such as an invoice header and invoice detail)

```
SELECT InvH, Line FROM InvHed join InvDet on (invH = invD) where VoidLine = ''
```

Normally when you join these together you get a list like this:

```
Invoice  Line
123456    2
123456    3
123456    4
123456    6
123457    1
123457    2
123457    3
```

Note that first detail line may not be coded as 1. Here it happens  to be 2.

I would actually like to structure an SQL statement such that the first detail line would repeat.

```
Invoice  Line
123456    2
123456    2
123456    3
123456    4
123456    6
123457    1
123457    1
123457    2
123457    3
```

Results should be sorted on Invoice/Line (added)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT InvH, Line FROM InvHed join InvDet on (invH = invD) where VoidLine = '' 
UNION ALL 
SELECT InvH, MIN(Line) FROM InvHed join InvDet on (invH = invD) where VoidLine = '' GROUP BY InvH
```

Note that you will need to specify ordering of results if that is important to you (you did not indicate it was in the question).

Answer (score 0):

This works, with Group and Order...

```
SELECT InvH, Line 
FROM InvHed join InvDet on (invH = invD) 
WHERE VoidLine = '' 

  UNION ALL 

  SELECT InvH, MIN(Line) as Line
  FROM InvHed join InvDet on (invH = invD) 
  WHERE VoidLine = '' 
  GROUP BY InvH, Line
  ORDER BY InvH, Line
```